# What is the difference between: "I am reading a lot these days" and 'I have been reading a lot these days'?

Tags: difference, tense, expressions, present-continuous, present-perfect-progressive

What is the difference between: "I am reading a lot these days" and "I have been reading a lot these days"?

As far as I can tell, they can both describe temporary situations. Can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, yes. However the first one is not that common. and many times this structure used with specific time periods, like "...this week" or "...this semester" to express things that we know or expect to absolutely happen in future.
As for second one it is better to end with "...lately" because it conveys the up to now sense of the verb.